# Best way to gain performance and do fast sql queries?

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm

I use MySQL for my database and i do some processing on the database side to make it easier for my application.

The queries i do used to be very fast until recently my database has lots of data and the queries are very very very slow.

My application do mainly statistics and has lots of related database to fetch data.

Here is an example:

tbl_game

```
+-------------------------------------+
|     id | winner | duration| endedAt |
|--------+--------+---------+---------|
|      1 |      1 |    1200 |timestamp|
|      2 |      0 |    1200 |timestamp|
|      3 |      1 |    1200 |timestamp|
|      4 |      1 |    1200 |timestamp|
+-------------------------------------+
```

winner is either 0 or 1 for the team who won the game
duration is the number of seconds a game took

tbl_game_player

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| gameId | playerId | playerSlot | frags | deaths | 
|--------+----------+------------+-------+--------|
|      1 |      100 |          1 |    24 |     50 | 
|      1 |      150 |          2 |    32 |     52 | 
|      1 |      101 |          3 |    26 |     62 | 
|      1 |      109 |          4 |    48 |     13 | 
|      1 |      123 |          5 |    24 |     52 | 
|      1 |      135 |          6 |    30 |     30 | 
|      1 |      166 |          7 |    28 |     48 | 
|      1 |      178 |          8 |    52 |     96 | 
|      1 |      190 |          9 |    12 |     75 | 
|      1 |      106 |         10 |    68 |     25 | 
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

The details are only for the first game with id 1
1 game has 10 player slots where slot 1-5 = team 0 and 6-10 = team 1
There are more details in my real table this is just to give an overview.

So i need to calculate the statistics of each player in all the games. I created a view to accomplish this and it works fine when i have little data.

Here is an example:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| gameId | playerId | frags | deaths | actions | team | percent | isWinner |
|--------+----------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+----------|
```

actions = frags + deaths
percent = (actions / sum(actions of players in the same team)) * 100
team is calculated using playerSlot in 1,2,3,4,5 or 6,7,8,9,10
isWinner is calculated by the team and winner

This is just 1 algorithm and i have many others to perform. My database is 1 milion + records and the queries are very slow.

here is the query for the above:

```
SELECT
    tgp.gameId,
    tgp.playerId,
    tgp.frags,
    tgp.deaths,
    tgp.frags + tgp.deaths AS actions,
    IF(playerSlot in (1,2,3,4,5), 0, 1) AS team,
    ((SELECT actions) / tgpx.totalActions) * 100 AS percent,
    IF((SELECT team) = tg.winner, 1, 0) AS isWinner
FROM tbl_game_player tgp
INNER JOIN tbl_game tg on tgp.gameId = tg.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        gameId,
        SUM(frags) AS totalFrags,
        SUM(deaths) AS totalDeaths,
        SUM(frags) + SUM(deaths) as totalActions,
        IF(playerSlot in (1,2,3,4,5), 0, 1) as team
    FROM tbl_game_player
    GROUP BY gameId, team
) tgpx on tgp.gameId = tgpx.gameId and team = tgpx.team
```

Comment: what does `explain select....` for the above query says ?

Comment: Also, hash keys may be helpful even more than indexing. Not using indexes makes your database really faster but only at the beginning. Can you show how you've created these tables?

Comment: What should it say normally? there are 2 primary, 1 derived and 1 dependent subquery. i don't know how to read the `explain select...` data. can you explain?

Comment: just copy them into the question.

Comment: i know. it returns me a table with some results, but i don't know how to use this result to find errors.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite obvious that indexes don't help you here¹, because you want *all* data from the two tables. You even want the data from `tbl_game_player` twice, once aggregated, once not aggregated. So there are millions of records to read and join. Your query is fine, and I see no way to improve it really.

<sub>¹ Of course you should always have indexes on primary and foreign keys, so the DBMS can make use of them in joins. (E.g. there should be an index on `tbl_game(tgp.gameId)`).</sub>

So your options lie outside the query:

- Hardware (obviously).
- Add a computed column for the team to tbl_game_player, so at least you save its evaluation when querying.
- Partitions. One partition per team, so the aggregates can be calcualted separately.
- Pre-computed data: Add a table tbl_game_team holding the sums; fill it with triggers. Thus you don't have to compute the aggregates in your query.
- Data warehouse table: Make a table holding the complete result. Fill it with triggers or at intervals.

Comment: by 1, do you mean that even if i have primary key or foreign key, i should create another index on it?

Comment: Most DBMS create indexes on primary and foreign keys automatically. I don't whether MySQL does so, too. If not, then yes, create them.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up indexes would speed up your queries. Queries can take a while to run if there is a lot of results, this is definitely a start though.

Comment: Should i add indexes on all my fields? i mean how do i proceed to know where to add an index?

Comment: @user2707590 no only apply indexes on field that will be use on join.

Comment: if a ffield is primary key or foreign key, should i still add an index on it?

Comment: Yes but only if using relations.

Answer (score -1):

for large databases Mysql INDEX can be very helpful in speed problems, An index can be created in a table to find data more quickly & efficiently. so must create index , you can learn more about MYsql index here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp